# Cloning a single branch to differently named branch in git

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on GitHub called `foo` with the following branches:

- master
- gh-pages

I have a second repo on GitHub called `<username>.github.com` (a user repo) with the following branches:

- master
- source

I would like to use the code in `foo->master` in `<username>.github.com->source` and be able to merge in changes from `foo->master` when they occur.

What is the best means of achieving this?

Comment: What is the actual use of ```source``` to be in the userpage repo? Should it be a fork, or a complete duplicate? Adding foo as a remote is not enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add `foo/master` as a remote, merge it in from time to time (do this in `<username>.github.com` repo):

```
# add foo as remote (once)
git remote add foo https://github.com/<username>/foo.git
# fetch from remote (often)
git fetch foo
# merge changes to source (when you want)
git checkout source
git merge foo/master
```

You can set `origin/source` as remote for `source` and `origin/master` as remote for master as normal.

You can also use `git fetch --all` to update all remotes, including `origin` and `foo`.

If you don't change much in `source`, then the merge will almost always be fast-forward.

---

You might want to set a remote url for foo that is read-only.
This way you can't push from `<username>.github.com` by accident and if it's a public repo, you won't need authentication (or password for your ssh key) for the fetch.

---

You can keep git from fetching the `gh-pages` branch with

```
git config remote.foo.fetch "+/refs/heads/master:/refs/remotes/foo/master"
git branch -rD foo/gh-pages
```

You just have to remember setting that when you expect any other branches than `master` to appear from `foo` remote.

A good explanation of the refspec is in the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html)

Comment: Technically you can also do ```git config --add remote.foo.fetch "+refs/heads/master:refs/heads/source"```. This way ```git fetch foo``` is enough to update ```source```. This **will** lead to problems when this wouldn't be a fast-forward! Only for complete duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following will help(I am not 100% sure of this though):

```
# Add a remote foo
git remote add foo <foor-url>

# create a foo-master branch
git checkout -b foo-master

# Set upstream branch for foo-master
git branch --set-upstream foo-master foo/master

# fetch code from foo master 
git fetch foo master

# reset the current branch to foo master
git reset --hard foo/master

# merge in source
git checkout source
git merge foo-master
```

To update foo-master:

```
git checkout foo-master
git pull
```